# Java returning before tasks complete

Tags: java, asynchronous, asynchttpclient

I have a method and it calls another method, for which the result is not important. To be exact, it is a POST request to a web service and the result is processed in that method and not in the calling method. Now I want the main method to return before that task finishes.

In essence, I need some sort of asynchronousity. What tools can I use in Java? Here are the steps again:

1. Method `A` calls Method `B`
2. Method `B` starts executing (we are not interested in the results of method b: it makes a call to a web service and processes the results itself)
3. Method `A` returns before Method `B` finishes

Comment: Add a callback in method B that runs once it has completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spring then its very easy and without any boilerplate code. Have a look at [@Async](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async) support in Spring. Here is a very [simple example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/) to get you quickly started.

```
@Service
public class YourClass {
    public void methodA() {
        methodB();
    }

    @Async
    public void methodB() {
        // Your POST logic
    }
}
```

To enable `async` support in your xml configuration, you need to have something like below

```
<task:annotation-driven />
<task:executor id="defaultAsyncTaskExecutor" pool-size="5-15" queue-capacity="100" />
```

Comment: Hi Jay, I am indeed using Spring and this is the solution I am currently leaning towards. Just looking at how to set up my xml config for this solution. Do you have any advice on that?

Comment: Updated the answer to have xml configuration

Comment: What if methodA() has a return value such as String.  Will this still work the same?  I am working through a similar issue and I haven't been able to get method A to return before method B completes.

Comment: @JimStevens yes it will just work the same as void method in above example

Comment: btw the [answer from Prim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34449649/471467) is also a nice neat way to do if you are using Java 8 or later. No dependency on framework supporting async mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CompletableFuture.runAsync()` to call method B async.

You can add a callback by calling `.thenRun()` on returned future if you want to do something when method B exited

Answer (score 0):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //Do whatever
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: please, explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to use AsyncHttpClient ,example

```
`AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient(
                                builder.setFollowRedirect(true).
                                setWebSocketTimeout(120000).
                                setAcceptAnyCertificate(true).
                                setMaxConnections(100).
                                setMaxRequestRetry(3).
                                setReadTimeout(120000).
                                setConnectTimeout(120000).
                                setRequestTimeout(120000).
                                build()); 
asyncHttpClient.prepareGet(url).execute(new AsyncCompletionHandler<Response>(){
                                @Override
                                public Response onCompleted(Response response) throws Exception{
                                      //your logic here
                                    }

                                @Override
                                public void onThrowable(Throwable t){
                                    //your logic here
                                }
                        });
```

`